# node-fluent-ffmpeg conversion to mp3 does not fire any "end" or "finish" event

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg, ytdl

I am downloading a video using ytdl-core and converting it to mp3 using node-fluent-ffmpeg. It seems that the code after the ffmpeg conversion gets executed before the conversion finishes as trying to upload the .mp3 file to a Google Cloud Storage bucket throws an error. I am trying to detect 'end' or 'finish' events but none are being triggered.

Code:

```
ytdl(url?.toString() as string)
    .once('data', (data) => {
      console.log('start', data);
    })
    .on('progress', async function (progress, downloaded, total) {
      console.log(parseInt(((downloaded / total) * 100).toString()) + '%');
      
    })
    .on('finish', async function () {
      console.log('Download finished...');
      
      console.log('using ffmpeg to convert into mp3');
      Ffmpeg({ source: `/Users/user/project/server/output/${videoId}.mp4` })
        .setFfmpegPath(ffmpeg.path)
        .toFormat('mp3')
        .saveToFile(`/Users/user/project/server/output/${videoId}.mp3`)
        .on('finish', () => {
          console.log('finished conversion');
        });
      console.log('after ffmpeg mp3 conversion');

      const storage = new Storage({
        keyFilename: `./key.json`,
      });

      const bucketName = 'bucketname';
      const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
      let mp3_url;
      console.log(
        fs.existsSync(`/Users/user/project/server/output/${videoId}.mp3`)
      ); // returns false
      bucket.upload(
        `/Users/user/project/server/output/${videoId}.mp3`,
// Error uploading: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/me/project/server/output/RMvenf7E-Dg.mp3'
        {
          destination: `${userId}/${videoId}.mp3`,
        },
        function (err, file) {
          if (err) {
            console.error(`Error uploading: ${err}`);
          } else {
            console.log(`mp3 uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
            console.log(file?.publicUrl());
          }
        }
      );

      
    .pipe(
      fs.createWriteStream(`/Users/me/project/server/output/${videoId}.mp4`)
    );

  console.log('after download and conversion');

  req.on('close', async () => {
    res.end();
  });
```

```
Error uploading: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/polo/makeklips/server/output/RMvenf7E-Dg.mp3'
[1] /Users/me/project/server/node_modules/.pnpm/fluent-ffmpeg@2.1.2/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js:182
[1]           handleExit(new Error('ffmpeg exited with code ' + code));
[1]                      ^
[1] Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Output #0, mp3, to '/Users/me/project/server/output/RMvenf7E-Dg.mp3':
[1] Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple paths for your file (double check what the `${userId}` is).

1. You are piping output to `/Users/me/[...]`,  but after you are
2. trying to upload from `/User/user/[...]` and
3. The error says `/Users/polo/makeklips/server/`